# How can I integrate a MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a MySQL subquery that I need to incorporate into my main query but i'm not sure how.  My main query is shown below.  I want to run that and as part of the same query run the subquery and get the result from that (which happens to be a sum) and then compare the result of the subquery in the main MySQL statement.

**Main query**

```
select * from employees_timesheet where 
        (sign_off_1 = 'Director' or sign_off_2 = 'Director' or sign_off_3 = 'Director') 
        and
            (case when sign_off_1 <> 'Director' and sign_off_1_status = 'Compete' 
                then 1
                else 0
            end 
            + case when sign_off_2 <> 'Director' and sign_off_2_status = 'Compete' 
                then 1
                else 0
            end 
            + case when sign_off_3 <> 'Director' and sign_off_3_status = 'Compete' 
                then 1
                else 0
            end) = {{{$sign_offs_required}}}
```

**Sub query**

```
select 
        SUM(
            case when employees_timesheet.sign_off_1 <> 'Director' 
                then 1
                else 0 
            end
            + case when employees_timesheet.sign_off_2 <> 'Director' 
                then 1
                else 0 
            end
            + case when employees_timesheet.sign_off_3 <> 'Director' 
                then 1
                else 0 
            end
        ) as sign_offs_required 
        from employees_timesheet
```

Any help is mch appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to compare? Can you show some sample data and the output you're trying to get? The main query gets each employee's signoff, the subquery gets the total for all employees.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to compare the result of the sub query (sign_offs_required) to make sure that it is equal to the result from the first query.  Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. The first query gets each timesheet's total, the subquery gets the total for all timesheets because there's no `GROUP BY`. How can they possibly be equal?

Comment: Can I just add a GROUP BY then?

Comment: Would this work? http://pastebin.com/NkHyHCeF

Comment: Please put it in the question, not an external link. And format it nicely, like your first two queries. If you want to make a link for demonstration purpose, use sqlfiddle.com.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using the following query:

```
select et.* from employees_timesheet et where 
        (et.sign_off_1 = 'Director' or et.sign_off_2 = 'Director' or et.sign_off_3 = 'Director') 
        and
            (case when et.sign_off_1 <> 'Director' and et.sign_off_1_status = 'Approved' 
                then 1
                else 0
            end 
            + case when et.sign_off_2 <> 'Director' and et.sign_off_2_status = 'Approved' 
                then 1
                else 0
            end 
            + case when et.sign_off_3 <> 'Director' and et.sign_off_3_status = 'Approved' 
                then 1
                else 0
            end) = 
                (case when et.sign_off_1 <> 'Director' 
                        then 1
                        else 0 
                    end
                    + case when et.sign_off_2 <> 'Director' 
                        then 1
                        else 0 
                    end
                    + case when et.sign_off_3 <> 'Director' 
                        then 1
                        else 0 
                    end
                )
        group by et.id
```